# How to plot data over time

Tags: python, excel

I have some calcium imaging data (measuring the intensity of a fluorescence molecule that responds to cellular calcium levels) in Excel that I can use for practicing Python. I imported the data into Python as csv, then tried to plot calcium concentration versus time. The trouble I have is, Python expect time to be expressed as Year-Month-Day-Hour-Minute-Second. But I only have Hour-Minute-Second. So want to ask, is Python always expecting time as Year-Month-Day-Hour-Minute-Second and therefore I just need to make up a day, or, can I use some command to tell Python to only use Day-Hour-Minute?

Comment: *Python* expects nothing. Some *libraries* which you are using, and which you have not specified, might contain functions which expect input in a given format. Please give a [mcve]. As it is, your question is almost impossible to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't expect anything, except that you give it a date. Or something date like. (To be perfectly fair, Python doesn't even expect that. You just need to give Python something date like if you want to to behave the way *you* expect.).

Probably the easiest way is to read the csv into a Dataframe, and then use `plot`. Once you've got that down, you can start looking at using [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/), or [Seaborn](http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial), etc.

So, assuming that when you say "I only have hour-minute-second" what you mean is that the date was the same for each point, you could do something like this.

```
import datetime

import pandas as pd

date = "20170707 "
times = ["09-00-00", "10-00-00", "11-00-00"]
timestamps = [datetime.datetime.strptime(date + time, "%Y%m%d %H-%M-%S") for time in times]
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"Ca": [2, 1, 3]}, index=timestamps)
df.plot()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Looking at your code, I realize that I need to backtrack a bit and learn more about Python codes before continuing on the 'Intro to Data Visualization with Python' course on Datacamp... Still don't understand fully the different types of data series. Will get back here when I really 'gets it'. Thanks.